# Hide variable in URL

Tags: php, url, opencart

I am working on a OpenCart based eCommerce website and would like to know how to hide the variables passed in a URL. The reason I want to do this is that we allow the customer to print their invoice at the end of a successful transaction and the structure of the URL is as follows:-

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/invoice/standard&order_id=1000010
```

Now the thing is, if you change the last value of the **order_id** to anything else or even change any of the other digits, it will show you the invoice for that order number and if that **order_id** belongs to another customer, it will show their details to this customer.

So now what I would like to know is that is there a good way to encrypt this url and decrypt it on the server-side to complete the request without showing the user **order_id**.

Please let me know if you need anymore info and I'll try and add it to my question.

Comment: You can't use `POST` data for some reason? Also if orders are secure info you should only allow them to be shown to proper, authorized users any way, since it'd be a security risk regardless.

Comment: There is something called `POST` method and `HIDDEN` variables sending.

Comment: Why not hold the variable in session ?

Comment: Sounds like the correct solution to this problem is to prevent customers seeing invoices that are not theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this really, instead you should be validating the logged in user for that invoice within the model/DB File.

For example....

I assume as it stands, your DB query would be similar to this:

```
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE order_id = `" . (int)$order_id . "`");
```

You should check also check the customer_id:

```
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE order_id = `" . (int)$order_id . "` AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
```

If the invoice is not owned by that customer, then no results would be found.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experience with Opencart, but chances are it checks whether the current user is logged in, and displays the invoice only if it belongs to them.

If that is not the case, the underlying problem should be fixed instead, and access to invoices limited to the customer (e.g. through a login system), instead of creating [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Opencart but I believe the `order_id` being displayed in the URL is not the big problem. The major issue here is that other users can view another user's invoice. You have to perform `access control` for non-public pages like these. ONLY allow the owner to look at their own invoice.

Now to answer your question, to prevent your order_id from being shown on the URL, you need to use `POST` data, currently you are using `GET`. You can access `POST` data using `$_POST`.

Comment: Using only a `POST` instead of `GET` **is really not a solution** - I can use whatever simplest tool to perform thousands of `POSTs` to Your site with auto incrementing `order_id` and You will then be very surprised how much information could I get...

Comment: You are correct. I didn't say `POST` instead of `GET` is the solution. I addressed the question in two parts, one in terms of security where I suggested `access control`. 

In the second part I did mention **to answer your question** where I stated clearly the way to prevent the order_id from being shown in the URL which is the exact question the asker wanted to address.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard feature, and as such you should contact the developer of the extension. If your store allows guest checkouts, then the URL should contain a random key of some sort, or the e-mail address attached to the order for instance to validate that the request is from an authorised user only. If the order is for a registered user then the `customer_id` assigned to the order should be validated against the current logged in user, and redirected to a login if the user is not logged in